# New union shorthand giving "unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'type'"

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.10

Before 3.10, I was using `Union` to create union parameter annotations:

```py
from typing import Union

class Vector:
    def __mul__(self, other: Union["Vector", float]):
        pass
```

Now, when I use the new union shorthand syntax:

```py
class Vector:
    def __mul__(self, other: "Vector" | float):
        pass
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'type'

Is this not supported?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The fact that it's being used as a type hint doesn't really matter; fundamentally the expression `"Vector" | float` is a type error because strings don't support the `|` operator, they don't implement `__or__`. To get this passing, you have three options:

1. Defer evaluation (see [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/)):

   ```
   from __future__ import annotations

   class Vector:
       def __mul__(self, other: Vector | float): ...
   ```
2. Make the whole type a string (effectively the same as deferring evaluation):

   ```
   class Vector:
       def __mul__(self, other: "Vector | float"): ...
   ```
3. Keep using the `Union`:

   ```
   from typing import Union

   class Vector:
       def __mul__(self, other: Union["Vector", float]): ...
   ```

You can see further discussion, without a resolution as yet, on [this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue45857).